# Windows does not upgrade from Vista to 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

I am trying to upgrade to Windows 7 from Windows Vista. When the windows 7 installer prompts me to restart, it boots into Vista like nothing happened.
I am currently using a Hewlett-Packard HP Pavilion dv4 Notebook PC running Windows Vista Home Premium. Here is what I did.

- I booted up the computer.
- I went to the boot menu by pressing `F9`
- I selected the USB Drive I had plugged in with Windows 7 in it.
- I went to the installer and select upgrade.
- It then told me to restart.
- I pressed and held down the power button until the power cut off, and then turned it back on.
- It booted into Windows Vista like nothing happened.

What should I do?

Comment: Start the Windows 7 installation from within Windows Vista

Answer (score 5):

You can’t upgrade Windows by booting from installation media.

If you boot from installation media, your only option is a clean install.

If you want to upgrade your OS, then you will need to start Vista, put in your installation media and run setup from there. Then you can upgrade.

I would suggest considering a clean install, rather than an upgrade. This is rarely ever a good choice as it carries over programs and settings from the old OS, and that means junk and problems too.

Keep in mind you can also not change the architecture of your OS during an upgrade. In other words, if Vista is 32-bit you can only use Windows 7 32-bit installation media, even if your hardware can run 64-bit.

Comment: You could use the 64-bit installation, but you wouldn’t be doing an upgrade of the existing installation, and you would be forced to replace your existing installation with a fresh installation